# dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _pthread_jit_write_protect_supported_np

Tags: npm, next.js

i upgraded my node version but because my mac version was too old i had to downgrade it back to V16.16.0 (and used `nvm use 16.16.0`) because else it wouldn't work. Now i get this error when i try to run `npm run dev` to start my next.js app. How can i fix this? I also tried downgrading my node to 16.0.0 but that also didn't work, i also already removed the node_modules and package-lock.json and did `npm install` again. I also already did `npm update` and `npm rebuild` so im kinda lost now.

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _pthread_jit_write_protect_supported_np
  Referenced from: /Users/user/project_folder/mysite.nl/node_modules/sharp/build/Release/../.././vendor/8.13.3/darwin-x64/lib/libvips-cpp.42.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _pthread_jit_write_protect_supported_np
  Referenced from: /Users/user/project_folder/mysite.nl/node_modules/sharp/build/Release/../.././vendor/8.13.3/darwin-x64/lib/libvips-cpp.42.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

Abort trap: 6
```

Comment: That's your sharp install. I'd check that your node version is supported on your mac's CPU type, then try redownloading that. https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install

Comment: Hi @jcupitt im busy with that atm but npm isn't working now so i'm fixing that and then i'll see if it works. I completely removed node and npm because some packages just kept using V19

Comment: @jcupitt what do i have to do after doing npm install sharp? It isn't working.

Comment: Check the sharp install guide and make sure your node version, sharp version and cpu (eg. if using M1) are all supported.

Comment: See: https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/3438.